# Dealing with campers in Fortnite

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I am quite the rushy style of people. However, the safest metagame at the moment would be to build a huge tower, hide in there and wait for the zone to shrink, then rince and repeat. They peek very little, making late game extremely boring: people on towers looking at each other, sometimes shooting a lost sniper bullet.

I have a hard time dealing with those people. I feel like the game is way more exciting when it comes to [building battles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFexhgcVK0w) and outsmarting your opponent, and I'd like to express this through my game style. However, it often leads to a loss, whether it's being shot in the back or simply not managing to reach the guy/guys at the top.

Does anyone have any advice / tips on how to deal with those kind of players ? On how to rush efficiently a tower-dude in Fortnite ?

Comment: Self built? A few RPG shots will deal with it

Comment: IIRC you can just destroy the base of the tower and it will destroy itself and in the end the enemy will fall to the ground and die

Comment: Problem is destroying it without being targetted by the guys on top. Same goes without explosives. Maybe I should carry explosives more often ...

Answer (score 5):

Well if you like building battles then rushing towers should be relatively easy as most techniques rely heavily on building. The techniques used to rush a tower are varied and depend on many factors:

- What items you have(launchpad,explosives etc.)
- The amount of materials you have
- The design of the tower and its height
- If the person in the tower hasn't noticed you yet or the presence of other enemies

### Using Explosives and Other Items

If you have explosive weapons such as the rocket launcher, grenade launcher, the new guided missile launcher, or normal grenades then you can attempt to destroy their tower from a relatively safe distance and proceed to rush them afterwards. This approach depends on the design of the tower and its height if its a 1x1 tower that's 5 walls high then you can shoot 2 or 3 rockets directed to the same floor level to bring it down. This is better than shooting the rockets directly at them as they can build the walls back faster then you can destroy them(unless you also shoot at them with your Assault rifle after each rocket this can be a valid tactic in certain situations especially when they are near the same level as you) . If you have grenades and you're close enough to the tower you can shoot a wall facing you(preferably the one attached to the ground) and then proceed to throw grenades inside the tower.
You can also use other items such as the launchpad and impulse grenades although both are a bit risky they're a great way to infiltrate a tower with a wide top as you can easily land away from the enemy which gives you time to build and to protect yourself.

### Using Building to your Advantage

It's very hard to explain building techniques using words only that's why I believe you should watch professional players streams or videos and focus on how they build up to towers as there isn't one good way to build to a tower that works for all situations. You should already have good experience with most of the building techniques used to attack a tower as a lot of them are used in build battles as well. [This video](https://youtu.be/3RRzFQObie4) shows two ways that you can use to attack a tower. Notice how in the first clip he builds walls around him every time he's not moving this protects him from getting shot by someone else and should be something you do whenever you're building but not moving in general. You should also watch other tutorial videos about attacking towers but this video is a good place to start. [The beginning of this video](https://youtu.be/F-SBJsn5zkQ) shows another way to attack a tower.

Answer (score 1):

A person with a lot of builds can't be out built, he has that advantage. Instead, focus on building 1 piece for movement, 1 for protection only. So wall ramp-run up a side-they shoot it out, rebuild while running forward. No momentum lost+you have a shield to your front. Get to their tower base and build roofs around the outside of it, then shoot out the legs. Roofs to protect you from above while you destroy.

Builder's lose to > minimal build to protect and shoot.

Answer (score -4):

Destroy the towers base then use a few traps to surround that person and use explosives